# How float image and text correctly using css

Tags: css-float

I want a format html using CSS so that I get the following:

> Image on the left, with subject and
>   body next to it on the right. I want
>   subject to be on one line and the body
>   to be on the other.
>   With One message after each other
>   on subsequesnt blocks downs the page.
>
> However I'm getting the subject and the body one one line and a cacade effect down the 
>   page.

Here is what I seem to be getting.

[image]
I just cannot seem to get the hang of what's needed.

My html is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>messages to/from someone</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="messages.css" />
</head><body>
         <div class'message'>
               <span class='to'>
                     <img class='floatimgleft' src='../code/images/arrow-right.png' width='64' height='64' border='0' />
                     <span class='subject'>subject</span>
                     <span class='body'>body</span>
               </span>
         </div>  
         <div class'message'>
               <span class='to'>
                     <img class='floatimgleft' src='../code/images/arrow-right.png' width='64' height='64' border='0' />
                     <span class='subject'>subject</span>
                     <span class='body'>body</span>
               </span>
         </div>  
         <div class'message'>
               <span class='to'>
                     <img class='floatimgleft' src='../code/images/arrow-right.png' width='64' height='64' border='0' />
                     <span class='subject'>subject</span>
                     <span class='body'>body</span>
               </span>
         </div>  
</body></html>
```

My CSS is:

```
.floatimgleft {
    float:left;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.message{
  display: block;
}

.subject {
   display: inline;
}
.body {
   display: inline;
}
```

Edit: I've edited the code to show where I started from. I was under the impression that div class='message' would cause a line break between messages but I'm getting a cascade effect.

Comment: This might be a very stupid answer but I don't see the *floatimgleft* CSS class being used in your HTML.

Comment: There are several options to end a float. like adding a br or a div with a css rule like: clear: both; to it below to image and text. However not all browsers will handling it the right way (ahum ahum IE). If you really need to end a float my experience is to add a div around the image and text en set to css of it to: zoom: 1; overflow: auto; is your best option in such a case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
class="floatimgleft"
```

to your `img` tags:

```
<img src='../code/images/arrow-right.png' width='64' height='64' border='0' class="floatimgleft" />
```

Also, seems you are not using `to` class either and you are missing `=` in the `<div class'message'>`.

Here's a jsfiddle to test it out:

- http://jsfiddle.net/CdBSU/

EDIT: For having it clear, add `clear: left` to message. See the fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/CdBSU/2/

for a demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

For the layout you were looking for, I would probably go with something more like:

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>messages to/from someone</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="messages">
        <li>
            <div>
                <span class="icon"></span>
                <h2>Subject</h2>
                <p>Body.. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>
                <span class="icon"></span>
                <h2>Subject</h2>
                <p>Body.. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Style.css:

```
h2, p { clear: none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; }
ul#messages { text-align: left; }
ul#messages li { margin-bottom: 25px; }
ul#messages li > div > span.icon { float: left; display: block; width: 64px; height: 64px; border: 1px solid #111; /* border added to demonstrate */ background-image: url('../code/images/arrow-right.png'); }
```

Demonstrated at: http://jsfiddle.net/j7KHg/2/

Comment: I've just generated the again but I cannot get this work with an external CSS - http://jsfiddle.net/j7KHg/1/

Comment: I have added it to an external CSS and archived it. Works fine.. http://www.speedyshare.com/files/25534991/example.zip

Comment: Download the example (archive) that I linked to in the comment above. That shows that it works. It might be your reference to the CSS. Or that you modify the HTML incorrectly afterwards. If you copy what's in my archive and run it, it should work.